# Spring boot - Rest Service - Getting random HTTP status 400

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I could not find why is the cause ... but I am getting randomly Http 400, param not present:

```
Required String parameter 'id' is not present.
```

I am getting this in Postman and different Rest Client,

this is my code :

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/borrower", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    public ResponseEntity<?> borrower(@RequestParam(value = "id") String cuit, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token)  throws Exception {

           // some business code
       return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

I'm using Spring boot 2.0.1

[image]

Comment: what happens if you rename the incoming parameter from `cuit` to `id`? (in the `borrower(...)` method signature)

Comment: I could try that.

Comment: you sure your code compiles?

Comment: @MarkoPacak fixed

Comment: as first step, as always, try to put `@ResponseBody` before the return type `ResponseBody<?>`

Comment: @ochi should be something else ... I change param name ... still having some random 400.

Comment: @MarkoPacak should be something else too. Updated to RequestBody ... and still getting 400.

Comment: We could help you in a more effective manner if you shared a sample that we can run ourselves rather than having folks guessing what the problem might be.

Comment: I Found the root cause ... I have a

Answer (score -1):

What if you try it like this?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getStuff(@PathVariable("id") long id) { 
    //the long id defined is the variable passed when making the petition through postman
    Entity entity =  entityService.getById(id);
    //for the entity it is supposed to be your model, and service
    if (entity == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO>(new ErrorDTO(
         // the ErrorDTO is a file where you get all the descriptions
                "did not find any id  " + id), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Entity>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Because i've got some downvotes i'm not able to comment and people didn't understood what i said.. so in other words it goes like this.. EDITED

Comment: Welcome @Cesar Kemper, Please describe your solution :).